# Need help for a query

Tags: database, codeigniter

my current query is:

```html
public function teachers_manage() {

     
      $this->db->select('users.user_id, teacher_id, COUNT(student_id) AS S, COUNT(DISTINCT(users.class)) AS C, schools.region, schools.school_name');      
      $this->db->from('teacher_student_conn');      
      $this->db->join('users', 'teacher_student_conn.student_id=users.user_id','left');
     
      $this->db->join('schools', 'schools.school_id=users.school_id');
      $this->db->where('users.deactivated_at = "0000-00-00 00:00:00" OR users.deactivated_at IS NULL ');
      
      $this->db->where('users.role_id', '1');
      $this->db->group_by("teacher_student_conn.teacher_id");
      $result=$this->db->get();
        return $result->result();
        
  }
```

It shows me teachers and for each teacher number of classes he teaches and number of students he teaches. I have made join 2 tables - `users` and `teacher_student_conn` by `users=user_id=teacher_student_conn.student_id` and I've put where clause for student not to be deactivated - shows active students. But how to do that also fot the teachers? Another join will change the results. I only want to add where clause for teachers to be active.
My tables look like this:

### `users`

- user_id
- school_id
- class
- role_id
- created_at
- deactivated_at

  ### teacher-student_conn
- id
- teacher_id
- student_id
- created_at

Comment: *But how to do that also for the teachers? Another join will change the results.* - If you use LEFT JOIN, the same way you did for USERS table, it will not change results.

Comment: I secceeded. Now it works with these 2 joins, it shows correct results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to add a column for "status" to more easily distinguish the status of student and teacher. 
And this is my recommended query

SQL Query:

```
  select 
    from users a
    join teacher-student_conn b on a.user_id = b.student_id
    join schools c on c.school_id = a.school_id
    where (a.status = "Deactivated") and (b.status = "Deactivated")
```

For codeigniter:

```
  $this->db->select('a.user_id, b.teacher_id, COUNT(b.student_id) AS S, COUNT(DISTINCT(a.class)) AS C, c.region, c.school_name');
  $this->db->join('teacher_student_conn b', 'b.student_id = a.user_id','left');

  $this->db->join('schools c', 'c.school_id = a.school_id');
  $this->db->where('a.status = "Deactivated" or b.status = "Deactivated" ');

  $this->db->where('a.role_id', '1');
  $this->db->group_by("b.teacher_id");
  $result=$this->db->get("users a");
  return $result->result();
```

Comment: I have only one column `deactivated_at` in table `users`. That's why I needed join. But in another case, it would be fine. :) :)

Comment: @iveto its very easy to track if you add more column for me as i said. But it's your choice.